# excel vba run sql query on entire array

Tags: excel, vba

I have an sql query that is running in a loop in excel.  It works while the array is small.  However the array is now up to around 4000 items and it causes excel to crash.  Is there a better way to do this, am I missing some easy way to do this

```
For k = 0 To ubound(sqlarray)

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim recst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sqlstring As String

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set recst = New ADODB.Recordset


conn.ConnectionString = "Driver={Client Access ODBC Driver (32-
bit)};System=mysys ;NAM=1;CurrentSchema=myschema;"
conn.Open


Sql = "Select ACCOUNT_NBR, ASSIGNED_TO from prodlib.gr_exp_account where 
account_nbr in ('" & sqlarray(k) & "' )"

Set recst.ActiveConnection = conn

recst.Open Sql, conn
Sheets("recst").Range("A" & k).CopyFromRecordset recst


conn.Close

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Next k

End Sub
```

Comment: Why the loop? I would hunt you down and read you the riot act if I were the DBA. Why not just `SELECT ... FROM prodlib.gr_exp_account WHERE account_nbr IN ('cust1', 'cust2', ... .'cust4000')` and get it back in ONE result set. Then loop through that if you need to do crazy things with it.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in my comment above you should be submitting a single SQL statement and getting a single result set back. Looping through every customer and submitting SQL for it is bad.

Consider something like the following:

```
Sub whatever(sqlArray as string)

    'initialize these outside your loop next time too
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim recst As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sqlstring As String

    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set recst = New ADODB.Recordset


    conn.ConnectionString = "Driver={Client Access ODBC Driver (32-
    bit)};System=mysys ;NAM=1;CurrentSchema=myschema;"
    conn.Open

    'All the accounts in one list in one statement. Use array function 'Join' 
    'to make the array a comma delimited string (or comma with quotes as a delim)
    Sql = "Select ACCOUNT_NBR, ASSIGNED_TO from prodlib.gr_exp_account where 
    account_nbr in ('" & Join(sqlArray, "','") & "' )"

    Set recst.ActiveConnection = conn

    recst.Open Sql, conn

    'Drop the entire recordset in a sheet starting at "A1"
    Sheets("recst").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset recst


    conn.Close

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

If JOIN() has a problem with the size of the array, or your database is complaining about the number of accounts you are sending in at a time, you could still loop, but using bigger chunks:

```
Sub whatever(sqlArray As String)

    'initialize these outside your loop next time too
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim recst As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sqlstring As String

    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection



    conn.ConnectionString = "Driver={Client Access ODBC Driver (32-bit)};System=mysys ;NAM=1;CurrentSchema=myschema;"
    conn.Open

    Dim k As Integer
    Dim chunk As Integer

    'Set this to how many accout numbers you can squeeze through in a single request safely
    chunk = 400

    For k = 1 To UBound(sqlArray) Step chunk

        'reset this object in the loop
        Set recst = New ADODB.Recordset

        'All the accounts in one list in one statement. Use array function 'Join'
        'to make the array a comma delimited string (or comma with quotes as a delim)
        Sql = "Select ACCOUNT_NBR, ASSIGNED_TO from prodlib.gr_exp_account where account_nbr in ('" & Join_With_Limit(sqlArray, "','", chunk, k) & "' )"

        Set recst.ActiveConnection = conn

        recst.Open Sql, conn

        Sheets("recst").Range("A" & k).CopyFromRecordset recst

        'close this for the next loop
        recst.close


    Next k
    conn.Close
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub

Function Join_With_Limit(inArray As Variant, strDelim As String, intLimit As Integer, intOffset As Offset) As String
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = intOffset To intOffset + intLimit
        'make sure we are below the ubound of the array
        if i > uBound(inArray) Then Exit For

        'If this isn't the first thing we are adding, then stick the delimiter
        'before dropping in the value
        If i <> intOffset Then Join_With_Limit = Join_With_Limit + strDelim

        'Add the next item
        Join_With_Limit = Join_With_Limit + inArray(i)
    Next i

End Function
```

Comment: So I know the loop is not the right way to go about it, when I try to to the join array it tells me that it is too long?

Comment: Is Join the issue, or is it when you submit 4000 account numbers, that your database throws an error?

Comment: Not sure, before when I tried this it gave me an error saying it is too long, no it is saying Conversion error on variable of parameter *N.  The debugger shows it stopping at recst.open line - I can do the query manually no problem with IBM I series so I doubt its the database not likeing it

Comment: If it's erroring on opening the recordset, then either the ODBC driver can't handle the size of the SQL request, or the database can't handle the size of the SQL or the number of incoming accounts in the list. I have updated the question to loop through the array, but in chunks that you can change to fit your needs. I have it set to do chunks of 400 accounts at a time. See how high you can make that before it barfs out an error, then you can just set it at that and leave it. I didn't test the code either, so there may be a bug or two in there, but it looks right.

Comment: smart - kind of got it working.  it loops through once but doesnt make it around the next time,

Comment: I made some changes. Most notably, I re-initialize the recordset object inside the loop and I moved that pesky conn.close to outside the loop. I think that should do the trick. I also updated the function to insure that we don't go over the upper bound of the array.